# Group Objects without a relationship

Tags: modeling

I would like to group objects but without a relationship. In other words, when you click on one, they all move without knowing which one is the father or the son.

The problem with the relationship is that if the parent moves, it is correct for the children to move, but if we mistakenly move or rotate a child, the scene is spoiled.

I'm not interested in Father and Son, I just want to group.

Comment: You can put them all in a collection, then select one and Shift G (Select Grouped) > Collection. Note: an object can be linked to several collections so you can keep them in their original collections if needed. You could also use Collection Instances but you won't deal with objects but instances.